# C++ Implementation of Mergesort of Linked-List Fails on Joining Sublists Of More Than 1 Node

Tags: c++, templates, mergesort

I have been working on a templated implementation of a linked-list, on purpose, to reinvent the wheel, to stumble into just this type problem to help learn the subtle nuances of pointer to class instance handling. The problem I have stumbled into has to do with merging sublists where on the second merge (the first merge where sublists can have multiple nodes) fails where a prior class instance (either from `split` or `mergesorted`) appears to go out of scope (which should not have any affect on the merge as the pointer assignment is the a prior list that always remains in scope until after the assignment of the original list node has taken place)

The key here is that all class instances have pointers to the original nodes from the original list, so as long as the sublist instance remains in scope until the beginning node of the sublist is returned and assigned to the list in the previous recursion. I am trying to move a perfectly-good 100% working C implementation. So it is a problem with my understanding of why I cannot treat class instances as I would a struct in C that is the issue here -- but I cannot put my finger on documentation that explains why.

The class `list_t` contains the struct `node_t` to form the list.

```
/* linked list node */
template <class T>
struct node_t {
    T data;
    node_t<T> *next;
};

template <class T>
class list_t {
    node_t<T> *head, *tail;
    int (*cmp)(const node_t<T>*, const node_t<T>*);

    public:
    list_t (void);                          /* constructors */
    list_t (int(*f)(const node_t<T>*, const node_t<T>*));
    ~list_t (void);                         /* destructor */
    list_t (const list_t&);                 /* copy constructor */
    /* setter for compare function */
    ,,,
    list_t split (void);                    /* split list ~ 1/2 */
    ...
    /* merge lists after mergesort_start */
    node_t<T> *mergesorted (node_t<T> *a, node_t<T> *b);
    void mergesort_run (list_t<T> *l);      /* mergesort function */
    void mergesort (void);                  /* wrapper for mergesort */
};
```

(yes I know no `_t` suffix, that's not the point here)

The `split` function is working fine and is:

```
/* split list l into lists a & b */
template <class T>
list_t<T> list_t<T>::split (void)
{
    list_t<T> s;                /* new instance of class */

    node_t<T> *pa = head,       /* pointer to current head */
            *pb = pa->next;     /* 2nd pointer to double-advance */

    while (pb) {                /* while not end of list */
        pb = pb->next;          /* advance 2nd ptr */
        if (pb) {               /* if not nullptr */
            pa = pa->next;      /* advance current ptr */
            pb = pb->next;      /* advance 2nd ptr again */
        }
    }

    s.tail = tail;              /* 2nd half tail will be current tail */
    tail = pa;                  /* current tail is at pa */

    s.head = pa->next;          /* 2nd half head is next ptr */
    pa->next = nullptr;         /* set next ptr NULL to end 1st 1/2 */

    return s;                   /* return new instance */
}
```

For the mergesort, I have a wrapper that calls the actual mergesort function `mergesort_run`. This was done so updating the `tail` pointer is only called after the sort completes, e.g.

```
/* wrapper to the actual mergesort routing in mergesort_run */
template <class T>
void list_t<T>::mergesort(void)
{
    mergesort_run (this);

    /* set tail pointer to last node after sort */
    for (node_t<T> *pn = head; pn; pn = pn->next)
        tail = pn;
}
```

`mergesort_run` is as follows:

```
/* split and merge splits in sort order */
template <class T>
void list_t<T>::mergesort_run (list_t<T> *l) 
{ 
    /* Base case -- length 0 or 1 */
    if (!l->head || !l->head->next) { 
        return; 
    } 

    /* Split head into 'a' and 'b' sublists */
    list_t<T> la = l->split(); 

    /* Recursively sort the sublists */
    mergesort_run(l); 
    mergesort_run(&la);

    /* merge the two sorted lists together */
    l->head = mergesorted (l->head, la.head);
}
```

The merge function, `mergesorted` merges the sublist in sort order:

```
template <class T>
node_t<T> *list_t<T>::mergesorted (node_t<T> *a, node_t<T> *b) 
{ 
    node_t<T> *result = nullptr;

    /* Base cases */
    if (!a) 
        return (b); 
    else if (!b) 
        return (a); 

    /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
    if (cmp (a, b) <= 0) { 
        result = a; 
        result->next = mergesorted (a->next, b); 
    } 
    else { 
        result = b; 
        result->next = mergesorted (a, b->next); 
    }

    return result; 
}
```

**Working C Implementation I am Moving From**

Each of the above (other than me splitting out the initial wrapper) is an implementation from the following working C split/mergesort:

```
/* split list l into lists a & b */
void split (list_t *l, list_t *a)
{
    node_t  *pa = l->head,
            *pb = pa->next;

    while (pb) {
        pb = pb->next;
        if (pb) {
            pa = pa->next;
            pb = pb->next;
        }
    }

    a->tail = l->tail;
    l->tail = pa;

    a->head = pa->next;
    pa->next = NULL;
}

/* merge splits in sort order */
node_t *mergesorted (node_t *a, node_t *b) 
{ 
    node_t  *res = NULL;

    /* base cases */
    if (!a) 
        return (b); 
    else if (!b) 
        return (a); 

    /* Pick either a or b, and recurse */
    if (a->data <= b->data) { 
        res = a; 
        res->next = mergesorted (a->next, b); 
    } 
    else { 
        res = b; 
        res->next = mergesorted (a, b->next); 
    } 
    return res; 
} 

/* sorts the linked list by changing next pointers (not data) */
void mergesort (list_t *l) 
{ 
    list_t la;
    node_t *head = l->head; 

    /* Base case -- length 0 or 1 */
    if (!head || !head->next) { 
        return; 
    } 

    /* Split head into 'a' and 'b' sublists */
    split (l, &la); 

    /* Recursively sort the sublists */
    mergesort(l); 
    mergesort(&la); 

    /* answer = merge the two sorted lists together */
    l->head = mergesorted (l->head, la.head);

    /* set tail pointer to last node after sort */
    for (head = l->head; head; head = head->next)
        l->tail = head;
}
```

**On 2nd Merge The Nodes From The 1st Merge Vanish**

I have stepped through the C++ implementation with `gdb` and `valgrind`. In `gdb` the code will complete without error, but in `valgrind` you have the invalid read of 4 and 8 bytes after a block that has been freed suggesting the destructor is freeing memory (which it should) but that the pointer assignments done as the recursion unwinds has a dependence on the *address of* the pointer from the nested recursive call instead of just using the values at the address from the original (as the above C code does perfectly)

What is happening is that after the list is split down to sublists with a single node and the first merge takes place -- we are still good. When the next unwind happens where you would merge the combined node with another sublist -- the values of the 2-node sublist are lost. So after picking though the C and C++ implementations, I am feeiling like an idiot, because problems I could simply debug/correct in C I am missing some critial understanding that allows me to do the same with a C++ class implementation of the same code.

**Test Code**

int main (void) {

```
    list_t<int> l;

    int arr[] = {12, 11, 10, 7, 4, 14, 8, 16, 20, 19, 
                  2, 9, 1, 13, 17, 6, 15, 5, 3, 18};
    unsigned asz = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < asz; i++)
        l.addnode (arr[i]);

    l.prnlist();
#ifdef ISORT
    l.insertionsort();
#else
    l.mergesort();
#endif
    l.prnlist();
}
```

The beginning merge of the left-sublist after it is split down to nodes `12` and `11` goes fine. As soon as I go to merge the `11, 12` sublist with `10` -- the `11, 12` sublist values are gone.

**MCVE**

```
#include <iostream>

/* linked list node */
template <class T>
struct node_t {
    T data;
    node_t<T> *next;
};

/* default compare function for types w/overload (ascending) */
template <typename T>
int compare_asc (const node_t<T> *a, const node_t<T> *b)
{
    return (a->data > b->data) - (a->data < b->data);
}

/* compare function for types w/overload (descending) */
template <typename T>
int compare_desc (const node_t<T> *a, const node_t<T> *b)
{
    return (a->data < b->data) - (a->data > b->data);
}

template <class T>
class list_t {
    node_t<T> *head, *tail;
    int (*cmp)(const node_t<T>*, const node_t<T>*);

    public:
    list_t (void);                          /* constructors */
    list_t (int(*f)(const node_t<T>*, const node_t<T>*));
    ~list_t (void);                         /* destructor */
    list_t (const list_t&);                 /* copy constructor */
    /* setter for compare function */
    void setcmp (int (*f)(const node_t<T>*, const node_t<T>*));

    node_t<T> *addnode (T data);            /* simple add at end */
    node_t<T> *addinorder (T data);         /* add in order */
    void delnode (T data);                  /* delete node */
    void prnlist (void);                    /* print space separated */

    list_t split (void);                    /* split list ~ 1/2 */

    void insertionsort (void);              /* insertion sort list */

    /* merge lists after mergesort_start */
    node_t<T> *mergesorted (node_t<T> *a, node_t<T> *b);
    void mergesort_run (list_t<T> *l);      /* mergesort function */
    void mergesort (void);                  /* wrapper for mergesort */
};

/* constructor (default) */
template <class T>
list_t<T>::list_t (void)
{
    head = tail = nullptr;
    cmp = compare_asc;
}

/* constructor taking compare function as argument */
template <class T>
list_t<T>::list_t (int(*f)(const node_t<T>*, const node_t<T>*))
{
    head = tail = nullptr;
    cmp = f;
}

/* destructor free all list memory */
template <class T>
list_t<T>::~list_t (void)
{
    node_t<T> *pn = head;
    while (pn) {
        node_t<T> *victim = pn;
        pn = pn->next;
        delete victim;
    }
}

/* copy ctor - copy exising list */
template <class T>
list_t<T>::list_t (const list_t& l)
{
    cmp = l.cmp;                        /* assign compare function ptr */
    head = tail = nullptr;              /* initialize head/tail */

    /* copy data to new list */
    for (node_t<T> *pn = l.head; pn; pn = pn->next)
        this->addnode (pn->data);
}

/* setter compare function */
template <class T>
void list_t<T>::setcmp (int(*f)(const node_t<T>*, const node_t<T>*))
{
    cmp = f;
}

/* add using tail ptr */
template <class T>
node_t<T> *list_t<T>::addnode (T data)
{
    node_t<T> *node = new node_t<T>;        /* allocate/initialize node */
    node->data = data;
    node->next = nullptr;

    if (!head)
        head = tail = node;
    else {
        tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
    }

    return node;
}

template <class T>
node_t<T> *list_t<T>::addinorder (T data)
{
    if (!cmp) {     /* validate compare function not nullptr */
        std::cerr << "error: compare is nullptr.\n";
        return nullptr;
    }

    node_t<T> *node = new node_t<T>;        /* allocate/initialize node */
    node->data = data;
    node->next = nullptr;

    node_t<T> **ppn = &head,                /* ptr-to-ptr to head */
              *pn = head;                   /* ptr to head */

    while (pn && cmp (node, pn) > 0) {      /* node sorts after current */
        ppn = &pn->next;                    /* ppn to address of next */
        pn = pn->next;                      /* advance pointer to next */
    }

    node->next = pn;                        /* set node->next to next */
    if (pn == nullptr)
        tail = node;
    *ppn = node;                            /* set current to node */

    return node;                            /* return node */
}

template <class T>
void list_t<T>::delnode (T data)
{
    node_t<T> **ppn = &head;        /* pointer to pointer to node */
    node_t<T> *pn = head;           /* pointer to node */

    for (; pn; ppn = &pn->next, pn = pn->next) {
        if (pn->data == data) {
            *ppn = pn->next;        /* set address to next */
            delete pn;
            break;
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
void list_t<T>::prnlist (void)
{
    if (!head) {
        std::cout << "empty-list\n";
        return;
    }
    for (node_t<T> *pn = head; pn; pn = pn->next)
        std::cout << " " << pn->data;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

/* split list l into lists a & b */
template <class T>
list_t<T> list_t<T>::split (void)
{
    list_t<T> s;                /* new instance of class */

    node_t<T> *pa = head,       /* pointer to current head */
            *pb = pa->next;     /* 2nd pointer to double-advance */

    while (pb) {                /* while not end of list */
        pb = pb->next;          /* advance 2nd ptr */
        if (pb) {               /* if not nullptr */
            pa = pa->next;      /* advance current ptr */
            pb = pb->next;      /* advance 2nd ptr again */
        }
    }

    s.tail = tail;              /* 2nd half tail will be current tail */
    tail = pa;                  /* current tail is at pa */

    s.head = pa->next;          /* 2nd half head is next ptr */
    pa->next = nullptr;         /* set next ptr NULL to end 1st 1/2 */

    return s;                   /* return new instance */
}

/** insertion sort of linked list.
 *  re-orders list in sorted order.
 */
template <class T>
void list_t<T>::insertionsort (void) 
{ 
    node_t<T> *sorted = head,       /* initialize sorted list to 1st node */
              *pn = head->next;     /* advance original list node to next */

    sorted->next = NULL;            /* initialize sorted->next to NULL */

    while (pn) {                    /* iterate over existing from 2nd node */
        node_t<T> **pps = &sorted,  /* ptr-to-ptr to sorted list */
                *ps = *pps,         /* ptr to sorted list */
                *next = pn->next;   /* save list next as separate pointer */

        while (ps && cmp(ps, pn) < 0) {  /* loop until sorted */
            pps = &ps->next;        /* get address of next node */
            ps = ps->next;          /* get next node pointer */
        }

        *pps = pn;          /* insert existing in sort order as current */
        pn->next = ps;      /* set next as sorted next */
        pn = next;          /* reinitialize existing pointer to next */
    }

    head = sorted;          /* update head to sorted head */

    /* set tail pointer to last node after sort */
    for (pn = head; pn; pn = pn->next)
        tail = pn;
}

/* FIXME mergesort recursion not working */
template <class T>
node_t<T> *list_t<T>::mergesorted (node_t<T> *a, node_t<T> *b) 
{ 
    node_t<T> *result = nullptr;

    /* Base cases */
    if (!a) 
        return (b); 
    else if (!b) 
        return (a); 

    /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
    if (cmp (a, b) <= 0) { 
        result = a; 
        result->next = mergesorted (a->next, b); 
    } 
    else { 
        result = b; 
        result->next = mergesorted (a, b->next); 
    }

    return result; 
} 

/* split and merge splits in sort order */
template <class T>
void list_t<T>::mergesort_run (list_t<T> *l) 
{ 
    /* Base case -- length 0 or 1 */
    if (!l->head || !l->head->next) { 
        return; 
    } 

    /* Split head into 'a' and 'b' sublists */
    list_t<T> la = l->split(); 

    /* Recursively sort the sublists */
    mergesort_run(l); 
    mergesort_run(&la);

    /* merge the two sorted lists together */
    l->head = mergesorted (l->head, la.head);
}

/* wrapper to the actual mergesort routing in mergesort_run */
template <class T>
void list_t<T>::mergesort(void)
{
    mergesort_run (this);

    /* set tail pointer to last node after sort */
    for (node_t<T> *pn = head; pn; pn = pn->next)
        tail = pn;
}

int main (void) {

    list_t<int> l;

    int arr[] = {12, 11, 10, 7, 4, 14, 8, 16, 20, 19, 
                  2, 9, 1, 13, 17, 6, 15, 5, 3, 18};
    unsigned asz = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < asz; i++)
        l.addnode (arr[i]);

    l.prnlist();
#ifdef ISORT
    l.insertionsort();
#else
    l.mergesort();
#endif
    l.prnlist();
}
```

**Result of Insertion Sort -- Expected Results**

Compile with `-DISORT` to test insertion sort (working):

```
$ ./bin/ll_merge_post
 12 11 10 7 4 14 8 16 20 19 2 9 1 13 17 6 15 5 3 18
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

**Result of Mergesort -- Not Good**

```
$ ./bin/ll_merge_post
 12 11 10 7 4 14 8 16 20 19 2 9 1 13 17 6 15 5 3 18
 0 16108560 16108656 16108688 16108560 16108816 16108784 16108848 16108752 16108720 16109072 16108976 16108944 16109008 16108880 16108912 16109136 16109104 16109168 16109040
```

So I'm stuck. (and it is probably something simple I should see but don't) Why is the merging of the sublists failing? What is the critical piece of understanding of class instance in C++ verses C struct handling I'm missing?

Comment: FWIW, your MCVE crashes royally when run using Visual Studio 2019 with an invalid pointer of 0xdddddddd (which means you are accessing deallocated memory).  If you have a Windows machine, maybe you should get the community edition and run your code.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I have not run it on windows. (I have to reboot my current machine to get into W10 w/VS 2017). There is something funny going on here. That corresponds to the `valgrind` output, but doesn't explain the gcc/gdb treatment of the code. I have an older `gcc (4.8.5` on Leap, but I'll have to try on Arch and see if it is treated different there (compiling with `-std=c++11`)

Comment: Also, you didn't implement the assignment operator for your list class.  I don't know if it makes a difference, but you are returning `list_t` by value in one of your functions (`split`), and maybe this could have side effects by not implementing all of the "rule of 3" functions.

Comment: Yes, that is one area that I investigated. Recall `split` takes the original nodes from the complete list and simply breaks the list in half, (just as the C implementation does) and returns a struct/class by value containing pointers to the original nodes. If this is where my logic it failing due to the rule of 3 on `node_t<T>`, then that may make some sense, but I tested joining splits earlier. Let me run another quick test.

Comment: Yes, I recommend you fire up Visual Studio -- the bug is reproducible every single time.  Should be just a matter of a few runs to see what is causing it.

Comment: I can't believe it. See my last comment below the answer. @1201ProgramAlarm helped me stumble to the answer and disable the destrutor on the local copy of the class to keep it from wiping out the nodes it held. Freaking `la.head = nullptr;` at the end of `mergesort_run` was all it took -- and that was the key I was missing. The local copy destructor was wiping out the nodes it held after they were assigned to the joined list -- AARRGH!! (learning has occurred `:)` Now it sorts backwards and forward beautifully. (the best lessons are often the result of much frustration...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - as an alternative, the sort functions could operate on nodes instead of lists, which would also eliminate the list destructor. You might want to consider a [bottom up merge sort for a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists), since it can be up to 40% faster if the nodes are scattered in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Yes, I go back and forth on the node/list aspect. Since this was more an exercise to move a C implementation into a templated C++ implementation, I moved the list (which holds a tail-pointer to optimize insertions) rather than just implementing a node based list. However, for the mergesort, I could just pass the list to the wrapper and then pass a pointer-to-pointer to head in the original list and try the bottom-up mergesort.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - The merge function can be node_t * merge(node_t *, node_t *), inputs are pointers to the first node of each of the two (null-terminated) sub-lists, and it returns a pointer to the first node of the (null-terminated) merged list. This merge function could be used for both top down and bottom up merge sort. The list head and tail pointers only need to be updated once, when the merge sort is complete. For the bottom up merge sort, each element of the small array would be a pointer to the first node of a sub-list, similar to the wiki article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mergesort_run`, you have a local list `la` that contains half of your source list.  At the end of the function you merge the content of `la` back into the new list, but the variable itself still points at the nodes you merged.  When the destructor for `la` is run, these nodes will be deleted.

If you set the head node of `la` to a NULL pointer (`la.head = nullptr`) after doing the merge, then when the destructor runs there aren't any nodes for it to delete.

One unrelated issue is that you don't copy `cmp` in places when creating a new list (like `split`).

Comment: Yes, but since the nodes held by `la` are the original nodes, the assignment to the joined list prior to the destructor being call should be fine?? Right?

Comment: That also corresponds to the local `list_t la;` used in the C code which behaves as expected. That is what really has me scratching my head. A local C struct is fine there, but I can't find anything that says using a local C++ instance is treated differently.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The assignment is fine, in the sense that the nodes are copied over, but the original `la` data is unchanged (so both it and the new list will point at the same node).  When `la` is destroyed those merged nodes will be deleted, and half your result is invalid.  The C code is fine because it doesn't have destructors.  Since `list_t` has a destructor, the C++ code does things the C code doesn't.

Comment: I'm getting it now, the damn local instance points to the same nodes, but then the destructor runs and wipes them out -- that's the difference between the C/C++ struct/class handling in this circumstance!! (bingo) Now how would I disable the destructor? (I would normally set the T->head to `nullptr` to stop it running -- which should work here to) -- hold on!

Comment: **WHOOP!!** `la.head = nullptr;` is all that was needed at the end of `mergesort_run`!  (add that and I'll accept)